# Disable tabbing on whole div

Tags: jquery, html, tabindex

I have a quiz with multiple questions.. only one is shown at a time. But if user tabs on the page the quiz will be apart of the tabbing order.

Setting tabindex="-1" dont work in all browsers.. is there some other way? jQuery?
I need it to skip the whole div somehow...

Note:
I tried this:

```
$('.quiz').live('keydown', function(e) {
    var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which; 
    if (keyCode == 9) { 
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

But it didnt work.. :/

Neither did this:

```
$('.quiz').bind('focusin', function() {
    var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;
    if (keyCode == 9) { 
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }  
});
```

Comment: Or make a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) demonstrating the principle.

Comment: You maybe have a look at preventing the default behaviour in a keypress event. `e.preventDefault` and then focus the element you want to.

Comment: I did try that (see added note) but it didn´t work

Comment: Don't use live! :) hehe. It is [depricated](http://liveisdeprecated.com) use `.delegate()` or `.on()`.

Comment: Hehe.. you are right.. however it doesn´t solve my real problem :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/albertjan/5X5LH/12/

**js**

```
$(window).keydown(function(e) {
    var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which; 
    if (keyCode == 9) { 
        if ($(e.target).is('.quiz *')) {
            e.preventDefault();
        } else {
            wastab = true;
        }
    }
});

$('.quiz input').focus(function(){
    if (wastab){
        wastab = false;    
        $('#not-in-quiz').focus();
    }
});
```

​

Comment: This example will still set focus on first input when I tab. (At least using chrome).. what is the real differance in this vs my approach?

Comment: And if I want it to trigger only on class="quiz"?

Comment: well if I try to set a class instead it wont work?.. so wierd! (http://jsfiddle.net/5X5LH/13/)

Comment: That doesn't work because the tab event doesn't happen in the div. it happens on the window. Or on some other part of the Dom.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
//Set tabindex = -1 for all div childs
var divChilds = $('.quiz').find("*");
$.each(divChilds , function(i, elem){
    $(elem).attr("tabindex", -1);
});

//cancel tab click
$('.quiz').keydown(function(e) {
    var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which; 
    if (keyCode == 9) { 
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});​
```

Answer (score -1):

I have done complete solution bins. so, here i have placed demo link as below:

**Demo:** http://codebins.com/bin/4ldqp9r

**HTML:**

```
<div id="panel">
  <div class="quiz">
    <span class="header">
      Div-1
    </span>
    <p>
      Question-1? 
      <input type="text" tabIndex="1" />
    </p>
    <p>
      Question-2? 
      <input type="text" tabIndex="2" />
    </p>
    <p>
      Question-3? 
      <input type="text" tabIndex="3" />
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="quiz">
    <span class="header">
      Div-2
    </span>
    <p>
      Question-4? 
      <input type="text" tabIndex="4" />
    </p>
    <p>
      Question-5? 
      <input type="text" tabIndex="5" />
    </p>
    <p>
      Question-6? 
      <input type="text" tabIndex="6" />
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.header{
  border-bottom:1px solid #445599;
  display:block;
  background:#447797;
  padding:0px;

}
.quiz{
  background:#bbaadd;
  border:1px solid #445599;
  padding:2px;
  display:inline-block;
}
.quiz input{
  border:1px solid #113388;
}
.quiz input:focus{
  background:#d98866;
}
```

**JQuery:**

```
$(function() {
    $(".quiz:first input:first").focus();
    $(".quiz input").keypress(function(e) {
        var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;
        if (keyCode == 9) {
            e.preventDefault();

            if ($(this).parents(".quiz").next().find("input:first").length > 0) {
                $(this).parents(".quiz").next().find("input:first").focus();

                /*
              //OR Another way to find next input selector is:
              $(this).closest(".quiz").next().find("input:first").focus(); 
              */

            } else if ($(this).parents(".quiz").prev().find("input:first").length > 0) {
                $(this).parents(".quiz").siblings(".quiz:first").find("input:first").focus();

                /*
              //OR Another way to find next input selector is:
              $(this).closest(".quiz").siblings(".quiz:first").find("input:first").focus(); 
              */
            }
        }

    });
});
```

**Demo:** http://codebins.com/bin/4ldqp9r